# Am I allowed to enjoy work while following the path of Karma Yoga?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, yoga

Regarding the Bhagavad Gita and Karma yoga,

Am I allowed to enjoy the work I do while following the path of Karma Yoga?

If yes then doesn't that go against indifference attitude I am supposed to maintain?

Comment: you're supposed to be indifferent to the results of work, not work. otherwise, you can do a shoddy haphazard work and still say that you did karma yoga, which is wrong. enjoying your work is actually the easiest way to do karma yoga. because you're enjoying the work, not its results. and easiest way to enjoy your work is to do the work of your varna, or the family occupation, because all your past vasanas and karma in previous births led to your current birth in a particular family best suited for your interests.

Comment: but nowadays due to varna-sankara (mixing of varnas by inter-marriage and para-dharma), people are confused as to what their family occupation is, and try many different 'passions' e.g. a software engineer has hunting as a passion, or a business ceo has beer-crafting as passion.. it's a mix of genetics and as a result we have many jack of trades and masters of none

Comment: So the indifference is towards the results and not the activity of work itself? I think I get it now.

Comment: yep. suppose you do hard work in company, but the company has loss this year, you still get your salary right ? like that. suppose a solider fights bravely and dies, but they lose the war, the soldier still gets gallantry award right? like that. because there are much bigger universal forces that determine the exact outcome of our actions. and those forces are someone else's job. not yours. it's like playing cricket, you hit a ball high, and then focus on whether the fielder is going to catch or not. that's not in your control. but hitting the ball low or high is.

Comment: @curiousBro say for example someone in road is lying in an accident. What would your reaction be there? That time if you act out of compassion and love, its Karma Yoga. But if you act thinking of benefit of that work (thinking you would get a reward for helping a person) its no more than selfish nature. Now from this understand what is Karma Yoga! Sticking to basics of life, humanity is what Yoga teaches us. Forget about fancy words of detachment, attachments!

Comment: Karma Yoga is taking control of things which you can! Your actions. That which is not under your control, simply leave it! This is called Jnana - Wisdom for life!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Gita says

> 18.26 That agent is said to be Sattvika who is free from attachment, who does not make much of himself, who is endued with steadiness and **zeal** and is untouched by success and failure.

The word 'Zeal' definitely means that a 'Sattvika' doer of works is allowed to enjoy the work while following the path of Karma-Yoga.

That does not go against the indifference attitude as ine has to be indifferent to the FRUITS of action and not to the action itself.

Comment: Very nice reference. I would like to make further comments that, often people think that material purpose/benefit is the only cause of zeal. This is a wrong assumption. For a counter-example, suppose you are meeting your mother after 2 years. After meeting your mother, you would like to do her seva $\textbf{with zeal}$. In this example, there is no material purpose or benefit, but you will still feel the zeal.

Comment: @spkakkar yes, joy is a mental penomenon and not necessarily related to material gain.

Answer (score 1):

According to Bhakti Yoga, the purpose of your work is to please Krishna (or at least you should assume it).
For a devotee, pleasing Shri Krishna is thoroughly joyful.

All three yogas (Bhakti, Karma, Gyaan) are conceptually isomorphic.
QED